# What's the keystroke for SHIFT+ENTER to be written into a Interop.Word Document

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm writing text into a Interop.Word document and I would like to add one paragraph that has 2 sentences separated by SHIFT+ENTER (which makes the text be closer to each other), instead then a a full ENTER.

Is there a special character or way to achieve so?

Comment: On my system, Ctrl+Enter creates a page break... maybe you meant Shift+Enter?

Comment: when you are writing in Word ?

Comment: Yes {...filling the 15 character limit...}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When looking for answers about Office products, you should always start with recording a macro and seeing what is produced. When I did this, I typed "blah<SHIFT+ENTER>blah" then stopped recording. The resulting macro looked like this.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.TypeText Text:="blah" & Chr(11) & "blah"
End Sub
```

Looks like you just need to insert a char 11 in your text.

==========
So in C# this would be something like:

```
string s = "first line" + Convert.ToChar(11) + "Second line";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick function in VBA. The character appears to be 11. In word, press Alt+F11, double click the current document and paste this function and pregg F5 to run. You will see 4 character codes printed. The last one presumably denotes EOF or end of file.

```
Public Sub DisplayCharacterCodes()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As String

    Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Reset
    Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "1" & Chr(11) & "2"

    For i = 1 To Application.ActiveDocument.Characters.Count
        c = c & vbCrLf & CStr(Asc(Application.ActiveDocument.Characters(i).Text))
    Next i

    MsgBox c

End Sub
```

Comment: NewLine does the FULL CTRL. I need the soft one !!